# How to create / generate Bearer token with PowerShell?

Tags: azure-active-directory, bearer-token

How to create / generate Bearer token with PowerShell?
I need to find out a way to generate the bearer token with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ADAuthorityURL = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/"
$resourceURL = "https://AQAEducation.onmicrosoft.com/<<AppRegistrion(1)>>"
$AADuserName = "your_user_name@xyz.onmicrosoft.com"
$AADpassword = "<<PASSWORD>>"
$AADClientID="<<Application Id of AppRegistrion(1)>>"
Write-Host "Retrieving the AAD Credentials...";

$credential = New-Object UserPasswordCredential($AADuserName, $AADpassword);
$authenticationContext = New-Object AuthenticationContext($ADAuthorityURL);
$authenticationResult = [AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions]::AcquireTokenAsync($authenticationContext, $resourceURL, $AADClientID, $credential).Result;

$authenticationResult.AccessToken
```